# How boost message_queue transfer a pointer?

Tags: c++, boost

Here is the code

I wonder how does boost message queue can transfer pointer. 
Since I am a rookie, so could you please explain me more carefully?

Thanks

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

struct sss{
    int a;
    double s;
};

int main() {
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    message_queue mq(create_only, "message_queue", 8, 8);
    sss as;
    as.a = 2;
    as.s = 4;

    const void* addr = static_cast<const void*>(&as);
    mq.send(static_cast<const void*>(&addr), sizeof(addr), 0);

    struct sss* ptr;
    int s;
    int q;
    mq.receive(static_cast<const void*>(&ptr), sizeof(ptr), s, q);
    cout << ptr-> a << ptr->s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, this works for you, and now you'd like to understand why? Or is it that it doesn't work and you'd like to know how to get it to work?

Comment: No, it's not work, I would like to know how to get it work

Comment: You should read the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue